# some issue with Post method in WEB API MVC4 Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to Post Data in web api mvc4 but its not taking the value from all my field in HTML.The only value its taking is from ID.Please see the below code and provide me some solution.

```
$("#pst").click(function AddProduct() {
    //jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var item = {
        ID: $("#prodId").val(),
        Name: $("#name").val(),
        Price: $("#price").val,
        Category: $("#category").val()

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:49503/api/Products',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        ContentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('added Successfully');
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {

            alert('not added');
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you post your action method as well.

Comment: This code is not enough to answer your question.. you need to elaborate your question....!!

Comment: try to wrap Name, Price and Category with quotes to set them as string

Comment: I have been doing something similar recently and also struggled to get a JSON POST to a Web Api controller to work. You might want to try adding dataType = 'json' to your AJAX parameters. You might also want to try doing a GET instead of a POST and see if that works (even though it's semantically incorrect). Also, have you set your controller to HTTP.POST?

Comment: Let me elaborate my problem. When i click the Post button i get the alert from Javascript that "added successfully" and when i check it in XML i get the recored but only the ID get posted rest of the field Name and category shows null and Price get 0 by default. I want to Post all four Inputs.

Comment: I followed the below link and want to add the Post method in this project.http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: Try using Fiddler to see what is actually being sent. My guess is these fields are not defined as strings and therefore not being serialized properly in the Web API Controller. Also include the code for your Web API Controller if you want further help.